# Using a custom control in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, custom-controls

I have Googled for an answer to this question, but I cannot seem to find any good solid examples of this. I created a custom star rating user control called StarControl. The control is basically five picture boxes that are horizontally adjacent to each other and I have the following code:

```
public partial class StarControl : UserControl
{
    private enum StarTypes
    {
        Hollow,
        Filled
    }

    private readonly StarTypes[] _stars;
    private int _rating;

    public StarControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Locked = false;
        _stars = new StarTypes[5];
        _stars[0] = StarTypes.Hollow;
        _stars[1] = StarTypes.Hollow;
        _stars[2] = StarTypes.Hollow;
        _stars[3] = StarTypes.Hollow;
        _stars[4] = StarTypes.Hollow;
        Rating = 0;
        SetStars();
    }

    public bool Locked
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Rating
    {
        get { return _rating; }
        set { _rating = value; SetRating(); }
    }

    private void SetRating()
    {
        if (_rating == 0)
        {
            _stars[0] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[1] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[2] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[3] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[4] = StarTypes.Hollow;
        }
        if (_rating == 1)
        {
            _stars[0] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[1] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[2] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[3] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[4] = StarTypes.Hollow;
        }
        if (_rating == 2)
        {
            _stars[0] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[1] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[2] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[3] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[4] = StarTypes.Hollow;
        }
        if (_rating == 3)
        {
            _stars[0] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[1] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[2] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[3] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[4] = StarTypes.Hollow;
        }
        if (_rating == 4)
        {
            _stars[0] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[1] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[2] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[3] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[4] = StarTypes.Hollow;
        }
        if (_rating == 5)
        {
            _stars[0] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[1] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[2] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[3] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[4] = StarTypes.Filled;
        }
        SetStars();
    }

    private void SetStars()
    {
        pbStar1.Image = _stars[0] == StarTypes.Hollow
            ? Properties.Resources.star_hollow
            : Properties.Resources.star_filled;

        pbStar2.Image = _stars[1] == StarTypes.Hollow
            ? Properties.Resources.star_hollow
            : Properties.Resources.star_filled;

        pbStar3.Image = _stars[2] == StarTypes.Hollow
            ? Properties.Resources.star_hollow
            : Properties.Resources.star_filled;

        pbStar4.Image = _stars[3] == StarTypes.Hollow
            ? Properties.Resources.star_hollow
            : Properties.Resources.star_filled;

        pbStar5.Image = _stars[4] == StarTypes.Hollow
            ? Properties.Resources.star_hollow
            : Properties.Resources.star_filled;
    }

    private void PbStar1MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Locked)
        {
            pbStar1.Image = Properties.Resources.star_filled;
            pbStar2.Image = Properties.Resources.star_hollow;
            pbStar3.Image = Properties.Resources.star_hollow;
            pbStar4.Image = Properties.Resources.star_hollow;
            pbStar5.Image = Properties.Resources.star_hollow;
        }
    }

    private void PbStar1MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Locked)
        {
            SetStars();
        }
    }

    private void PbStar2MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Locked)
        {
            pbStar1.Image = Properties.Resources.star_filled;
            pbStar2.Image = Properties.Resources.star_filled;
            pbStar3.Image = Properties.Resources.star_hollow;
            pbStar4.Image = Properties.Resources.star_hollow;
            pbStar5.Image = Properties.Resources.star_hollow;
        }
    }

    private void PbStar2MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Locked)
        {
            SetStars();
        }
    }

    private void PbStar3MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Locked)
        {
            pbStar1.Image = Properties.Resources.star_filled;
            pbStar2.Image = Properties.Resources.star_filled;
            pbStar3.Image = Properties.Resources.star_filled;
            pbStar4.Image = Properties.Resources.star_hollow;
            pbStar5.Image = Properties.Resources.star_hollow;
        }
    }

    private void PbStar3MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Locked)
        {
            SetStars();
        }
    }

    private void PbStar4MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Locked)
        {
            pbStar1.Image = Properties.Resources.star_filled;
            pbStar2.Image = Properties.Resources.star_filled;
            pbStar3.Image = Properties.Resources.star_filled;
            pbStar4.Image = Properties.Resources.star_filled;
            pbStar5.Image = Properties.Resources.star_hollow;
        }
    }

    private void PbStar4MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Locked)
        {
            SetStars();
        }
    }

    private void PbStar5MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Locked)
        {
            pbStar1.Image = Properties.Resources.star_filled;
            pbStar2.Image = Properties.Resources.star_filled;
            pbStar3.Image = Properties.Resources.star_filled;
            pbStar4.Image = Properties.Resources.star_filled;
            pbStar5.Image = Properties.Resources.star_filled;
        }
    }

    private void PbStar5MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Locked)
        {
            SetStars();
        }
    }

    private void PbStar1MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && !Locked)
        {
            _stars[0] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[1] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[2] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[3] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[4] = StarTypes.Hollow;

            Rating = 1;
        }
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && !Locked)
        {
            _stars[0] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[1] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[2] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[3] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[4] = StarTypes.Hollow;

            Rating = 0;
        }
        SetStars();
    }

    private void PbStar2MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && !Locked)
        {
            _stars[0] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[1] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[2] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[3] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[4] = StarTypes.Hollow;

            Rating = 2;
        }
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && !Locked)
        {
            _stars[0] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[1] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[2] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[3] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[4] = StarTypes.Hollow;

            Rating = 0;
        }
        SetStars();
    }

    private void PbStar3MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && !Locked)
        {
            _stars[0] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[1] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[2] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[3] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[4] = StarTypes.Hollow;

            Rating = 3;
        }
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && !Locked)
        {
            _stars[0] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[1] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[2] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[3] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[4] = StarTypes.Hollow;

            Rating = 0;
        }
        SetStars();
    }

    private void PbStar4MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && !Locked)
        {
            _stars[0] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[1] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[2] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[3] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[4] = StarTypes.Hollow;

            Rating = 4;
        }
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && !Locked)
        {
            _stars[0] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[1] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[2] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[3] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[4] = StarTypes.Hollow;

            Rating = 0;
        }
        SetStars();
    }

    private void PbStar5MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && !Locked)
        {
            _stars[0] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[1] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[2] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[3] = StarTypes.Filled;
            _stars[4] = StarTypes.Filled;

            Rating = 5;
        }
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && !Locked)
        {
            _stars[0] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[1] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[2] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[3] = StarTypes.Hollow;
            _stars[4] = StarTypes.Hollow;

            Rating = 0;
        }
        SetStars();
    }
}
```

The control works just fine. On my form, I have a DataGridView control and I'm trying to dynamically populate the DataGridView with rows from a collection. The collection is simply a collection of this class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Rating
{
    public string VendorName { get; set; }
    public int VendorRating { get; set; }
}

public List<Rating> _myRatings;
```

`VendorName` is simply a string and `VendorRating` is an int, which represents a number between 0-5. By setting my `Rating` property on my `StarControl`, it will show that number of stars. What I'm trying to do is figure out how to make my `StarControl` user control show up on the `DataGridView`. Can someone please provide me with an example of how this is done?

I've seen [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7tas5c80%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the subject, but I don't think this applies to me because they are just inheriting from `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`, which my control is more complex then just a date/time text box.

Comment: **Solution**: WPF. winforms doesn't support complex UIs.

Comment: @HighCore -- Are you telling me its impossible to do unless I either switch to WPF or write my own DataGridView?

Comment: I'm not saying it's `impossible`. I don't really know whether is possible or not, I just know that all the horrible hacks it takes to do anything useful in winforms are completely useless and unneeded in 2013, when WPF is much better and customizable. The amount of effort it takes to do this in winforms is probably 10x of what it takes in current, non-obsolete technologies.

Comment: @HighCore -- WPF Actually wouldn't be a bad solution. Here's the problem: unbelievably, the company I'm writing this for only has their client computers upgraded to .NET 2.0. I've been trying to get them to upgrade to at least 3.5 so that I can have LINQ ability. They just won't do it.

Comment: you may want to consider to actually `not` do any non-standard, Rich UIs. winforms doesn't allow Rich UIs, only poor ones. show an integer number in that cell, instead of the star drawings. And if your client still has Windows XP (from 2001), they can't seriously demand otherwise. If they want current stuff they need current computers. If they have dinosaur computers they will get dinosaur products.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For such a purpose, you don't need such a control at all. The attachment with the `DataGridView` is a little tricky. I don't want to give you a solution following that approach, however I just want to share a little info on how to achieve it. Firstly, you have to calculate the *total displayed cells*, you have to need a *`List<YourControl>`* to store all the needed controls. These controls must have your `DataGridView` as their `Parent`. The number of these controls must be equal to the number of displayed cells. Then in the `CellPainting` event handler, you have to *update* the locations of all your controls in the list. We add location updating code in the *CellPainting* event handler because whenever the cell value and bounds are updated, the *CellPainting* is fired and will update your controls' `Location` accordingly. It's a little tricky but it **does** work. You can associate each control with each cell via some *reference* property, such as `Tag` property.

Now, I would like to share with you this better approach. You just to create a custom `DataGridViewCell` used as `CellTemplate` for a custom `DataGridViewColumn`. We have to do some painting with `GDI+` and write fairly much code. Note that, I write this demo for myself, but it was started after reading your question. Answering a question with such a full code is not really **funny**, it consumes much time, but as I said I intended to use this demo for myself, and now I just want to share with you. In fact to give you some idea, the code can be simplified much more:

```
public class DataGridViewRatingColumn : DataGridViewColumn {
    public DataGridViewRatingColumn() : base(new DataGridViewRatingCell()) {
        base.ReadOnly = true;
        RatedStarColor = Color.Green;
        GrayStarColor = Color.LightGray;
        StarScale = 1;            
    }
    bool readOnly;
    public new bool ReadOnly
    {
        get {
            return readOnly;
        }
        set {
            readOnly = value;                
        }
    }
    Color ratedStarColor;
    Color grayStarColor;
    float starScale;
    public Color RatedStarColor {
        get { return ratedStarColor; }
        set {
            if (ratedStarColor != value) {
                ratedStarColor = value;
                if (DataGridView != null) DataGridView.InvalidateColumn(Index);
            }
        }
    }
    public Color GrayStarColor
    {
        get { return grayStarColor; }
        set {
            if (grayStarColor != value){
                grayStarColor = value;
                if(DataGridView != null) DataGridView.InvalidateColumn(Index);
            }
        }
    }
    public float StarScale {
        get { return starScale; }
        set {
            if (starScale != value) {
                starScale = value;
                DataGridViewRatingCell.UpdateBrushes(value);
                if (DataGridView != null) DataGridView.InvalidateColumn(Index);
            }
        }
    }
}    
public class DataGridViewRatingCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell {
    static DataGridViewRatingCell() {
        //Init star            
        List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
        bool largeArc = true;
        R = 10;
        r = 4;
        center = new Point(R, R);
        for (float alpha = 90; alpha <= 414; alpha += 36)
        {
            int d = largeArc ? R : r;
            double radAlpha = alpha * Math.PI / 180;
            float x = (float)(d * Math.Cos(radAlpha));
            float y = (float)(d * Math.Sin(radAlpha));
            points.Add(new PointF(center.X + x, center.Y + y));
            largeArc = !largeArc;
        }
        star.AddPolygon(points.ToArray());
        star.Transform(new Matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, center.Y * 2));             
        //Init stars
        UpdateBrushes(1);                   
    }
    public DataGridViewRatingCell() {
        ValueType = typeof(int);
        ratedStarColor = Color.Green;
        grayStarColor = Color.LightGray;
        starScale = 1;
        UseColumnStarColor = true;
        UseColumnStarScale = true;            
    }                
    public override object DefaultNewRowValue {
        get {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    internal static void UpdateBrushes(float scale) {
        int space = 2*R;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (stars[i] != null) stars[i].Dispose();
            stars[i] = (GraphicsPath)star.Clone();
            stars[i].Transform(new Matrix(scale, 0, 0, scale, space * i * scale, 0));                
            brushes[i] = CreateBrush(new RectangleF(center.X - R + space * i * scale, center.Y - R, R * 2 * scale, R * 2 * scale));
        }
    }
    private static LinearGradientBrush CreateBrush(RectangleF bounds)
    {
        var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(bounds,Color.White, Color.Yellow, LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal);
        ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend();
        Color c = Color.Green;
        Color lightColor = Color.White;
        cb.Colors = new Color[] { c, c, lightColor, c, c };
        cb.Positions = new float[] { 0, 0.4f, 0.5f, 0.6f, 1 };
        brush.InterpolationColors = cb;            
        return brush;
    }
    private void AdjustBrushColors(LinearGradientBrush brush, Color baseColor, Color lightColor)
    {
        //Note how we adjust the colors, using brush.InterpolationColors directly won't work.
        ColorBlend cb = brush.InterpolationColors;
        cb.Colors = new Color[] { baseColor, baseColor, lightColor, baseColor, baseColor };
        brush.InterpolationColors = cb;
    }        
    static GraphicsPath star = new GraphicsPath();
    static GraphicsPath[] stars = new GraphicsPath[5];
    static LinearGradientBrush[] brushes = new LinearGradientBrush[5];
    static Point center;
    static int R, r;
    int currentValue = -1;
    bool mouseOver;
    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, 
        int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates elementState, object value, object formattedValue, 
        string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, elementState, value, formattedValue,
            errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.SelectionBackground & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);             
        if (rowIndex == RowIndex && (paintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground) != 0) {
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            if(Value != null) Value = Math.Min(Math.Max(0, (int)Value), 5);
            if (!mouseOver) currentValue = (int)(Value ?? 0);  
            PaintStars(graphics, cellBounds, 0, currentValue, true);
            PaintStars(graphics, cellBounds, currentValue, 5 - currentValue, false);
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.Default;             
        }
    }
    protected override void OnMouseMove(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        if (!mouseOver) mouseOver = true;
        if (IsReadOnly()) return;
        var lastStar = stars.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
                            .LastOrDefault(x => x.x.IsVisible(e.Location));
        if (lastStar != null) {
            currentValue = lastStar.i + 1;                
            DataGridView.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        }
        else if(RowIndex > -1) {
            currentValue = (int)(Value ?? 0);
            DataGridView.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
        DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
    }        
    protected override void OnClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
        base.OnClick(e);
        if (IsReadOnly()) return;
        Value = currentValue == 1 && (int?) Value == 1 ? 0 : currentValue;
    }
    protected override void OnMouseLeave(int rowIndex) {
        base.OnMouseLeave(rowIndex);
        mouseOver = false;
        if (IsReadOnly()) return;
        if (rowIndex == RowIndex) {
            currentValue = (int)(Value ?? 0);
            DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
        }            
    }        
    private bool IsReadOnly() {
        var col = OwningColumn as DataGridViewRatingColumn;
        return col != null ? col.ReadOnly : false;
    }
    private void PaintStars(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, int startIndex, int count, bool rated) {
        GraphicsState gs = g.Save();
       g.TranslateTransform(bounds.Left, bounds.Top);           
        var col = OwningColumn as DataGridViewRatingColumn;
        Color ratedColor = col == null ? Color.Yellow :
            UseColumnStarColor ? col.RatedStarColor : RatedStarColor;
        Color grayColor = col == null ? Color.LightGray :
            UseColumnStarColor ? col.GrayStarColor : GrayStarColor;
        float starScale = col == null ? 1 :
            UseColumnStarScale ? col.StarScale : StarScale;
        UpdateBrushes(starScale);
       for(int i = startIndex; i < startIndex + count; i++) {
           AdjustBrushColors(brushes[i], rated ? ratedColor : grayColor, rated ? Color.White : grayColor);
           g.FillPath(brushes[i], stars[i]);
           //g.DrawPath(Pens.Green, stars[i]);
       }
       g.Restore(gs);
    }        
    Color ratedStarColor;
    Color grayStarColor;
    float starScale;
    public Color RatedStarColor {
        get { return ratedStarColor; }
        set {
            if (ratedStarColor != value) {
                ratedStarColor = value;
                var col = OwningColumn as DataGridViewRatingColumn;
                if (col != null && col.RatedStarColor != value) {
                    UseColumnStarColor = false;
                    DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public Color GrayStarColor {
        get { return grayStarColor; }
        set {
            if (grayStarColor != value) {
                grayStarColor = value;
                var col = OwningColumn as DataGridViewRatingColumn;
                if (col != null && col.GrayStarColor != value) {
                    UseColumnStarColor = false;
                    DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Change the star size via scaling factor (default by 1)
    public float StarScale {
        get { return starScale; }
        set {
            if (starScale != value) {
                starScale = value;
                var col = OwningColumn as DataGridViewRatingColumn;
                if (col != null && col.StarScale != value) {
                    UseColumnStarScale = false;                        
                    DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public bool UseColumnStarColor { get; set; }
    public bool UseColumnStarScale { get; set; }
}
```

**NOTE**: The 2 classes `DataGridViewRatingColumn` and `DataGridViewRatingCell` should be placed in the same file because I declared a static internal method `UpdateBrushes` in the `DataGridViewRatingCell` and use it in the class `DataGridViewRatingColumn`, you can change the modifier if you want to place them in separate files. Look at the provided properties and use them to customize the look and feel of the stars. They are named in a self-explanatory way. Here is some code showing the usage:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewRatingColumn(){
     //init some properties here ...
 });
//To change the ReadOnly which allows user to rate or not, you have to cast
//the column to DataGridViewRatingColumn first, this behavior is caused by 
//the failing/abnormal behavior of overriding the ReadOnly (I had to use new instead).
((DataGridViewRatingColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[0]).ReadOnly = true; (default by false)

//You should also enable DoubleBuffered on your DataGridView to eliminate flicker
typeof(Control).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                              System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
               .SetValue(dataGridView1, true, null);
```

[image]

Comment: Wow I had no idea it was such a complex task to achieve some thing like this! I am going to use your answer as a guide to try and achieve what I am trying to do. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

best way show star rating in datagridview 
use unicode char

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Rating"].Index
          && e.Value != null)
        {
            switch (e.Value.ToString())
            {
                case "1":
                    e.CellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Red;
                    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    //e.CellStyle.Font
                    e.Value = (char)9733;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    e.CellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Brown;
                    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
                    e.Value = (char)9733;
                    break;
                case "3":
                    e.CellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Green;
                    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    e.Value = (char)9733;
                    break;
                case "4":
                    e.CellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Blue;
                    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                    e.Value = (char)9733;
                    break;
                case "5":
                    e.CellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Gold;
                    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gold;
                    e.Value = (char)9733;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```